# Error in socket.io programming of handshaking in android

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, android-layout

I have created server.js file and i have run

> npm install socket.io

And i have used gottox example to communicate with my socket from android device but i am getting an error of handshaking. Please help me out.

Here is my **server.js** file

```
    //settings
var websocketPort = 8080;

// start websockets
var io = require('socket.io').listen(websocketPort);
console.log('chat server is running on port ' + websocketPort);

//websocket communication
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
      // tell all clients who has connected
      var ipAddress = socket.handshake.address.address;
      io.sockets.emit('chat', {name: ipAddress, text: 'joined chat'});
      console.log('client [' + ipAddress + '] connected');

      // relay message of client to all other clients
      socket.on('chat', function(data){
            io.sockets.emit('chat', {name: data.name, text: data.text});
      });

      // tell all clients who has disconnected
      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            io.sockets.emit('chat', {name: ipAddress, text: 'left chat'});
            console.log('client [' + ipAddress + '] disconnected');
      });
});
```

And i have used gottox/socket-io-client for communicating socket from my android device .
The code is as below

```
    final SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://192.168.2.24:8080");
            socket.connect(new IOCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(JSONObject arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("TAG","Server said:" + arg0.toString(2));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
                    Log.e("TAG","Server said:" + arg0);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(SocketIOException arg0) {
                    Log.e("TAG","An Error " + arg0);

                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnect() {
                    Log.e("TAG","Connection terminated ");

                }

                @Override
                public void onConnect() {
                    Log.e("TAG","Connection eSTABLISHED ");
                    socket.emit("connection", socket);

                }

                @Override
                public void on(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1, Object... arg2) {
                    Log.e("TAG","server Started " + arg0);

                }
            });
//          socket.send("user message");
            socket.emit("connection", socket);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Everytime i am connecting i am getting error while handshaking.

```
 11-07 17:00:03.475: E/TAG(2524): An Error io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
11-07 17:00:03.475: I/io.socket(2524): Cleanup
```

Comment: plz have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725659/io-socket-socketioexception-error-while-handshaking-emulator

Comment: did you add network permission to manifest file and the network communication should be in separate from main thread

Comment: yes i have added permission in my manifest of <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Do your network communications in an ASYNC task

Comment: SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://192.168.2.24:8080"); if you want to open an http connection then USE HTTP post,put,delete method

Comment: For the socket you dont need to give http i think, just ip address and you need to bind to the port

Comment: It gives error of protocol not found.....